# SAPUI5 - complex model binding

Tags: binding, model, sapui5

I have this json model:

**model/data.json**

```
{
    "orders" : [
        {
            "header" : { "id" : "00001", "description" : "This is the first order" },
            "items" : [
                { "name" : "Red Book","id" : "XXYYZZ" },
                { "name" : "Yellow Book", "id" : "AACCXX" },
                { "name" : "Black Book", "id" : "UUEEAA" },
            ]
        },
        {
            // another order with header + items
        },

        .....
    ]
}
```

and I'm assigning it `onInit` to the view, like this:

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/data.json");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(reqModel);
```

I'm trying to display a list of orders in the first view (showing the id), like this:

```
var list = new sap.m.List({
    id: "mainList",
    items: []
});

var items = new sap.m.ActionListItem({
    text : "{id}",
    press : [ //click handler, onclick load the order details page ]
});

list.bindItems("/orders", items);

.... // add list to the page etc etc
```

What I cannot do, is connect each **order** to its **header->id**.. I tried

```
text: "/header/{id}"

text: "{/header/id}"
```

in the items declaration, and

```
list.bindItems("/orders/header", items)
```

in the list binding, but none of them works.. The **id** value is not displayed, even though a "blank" list item is shown..

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was one of those I tried (but I don't know why it didn't work at that time)

```
text: "{/header/id}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The ListItem acts as a Template for a list/array of objects. That's why you bind it against an array structure in your data:

```
list.bindItems("/orders", itemTemplate)
```

That makes bindings of the ListItem relative to `/orders` and therefore your item should look like this without leading '/' (absolute paths would look like this `/orders/0/header/id` asf.):

```
var itemTemplate = new sap.m.ActionListItem({
    text : "{header/id}",
    press : [ //click handler, onclick load the order details page ]
});
```

Not quite sure how you made it work the way you have shown... May be it's not as picky as I thought.

Btw: For whatever reason the `ResourceModel` builds an exception of that syntax. You can always omit the leading '/' when dealing with `ResourceModels` (probably because they do not allow nested structures).

BR
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Cannot add comments yet, therefore an answer to you solved Problem, that could answer the initial problem. (And inform People using that example in any way)

In the current code listing you use the variable "reqModel" to set the model, but the variable with the model in it is named "model" in the line before. Maybe that was the first reason why both of your examles would not work?

Perhaps this error was cleared on rewriting some passages while testing.

greetings! -nx